# Last consonant of a text

Tags: c++

After a user enters a text (with spaces), how do I delete only the last consonant of that certain text?

I have no idea how to do that, whatever I did by now deleted all the consonants.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and why it isn't working? This is probably a good use case for [`std::string::find_last_of`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/)

Comment: `find_last_not_of` if it only contains letters, or `find_last_of` if it might contain other characters as well.

Comment: It might help to show what data structure you are using to store the text: char[], std:array<char> std::vector<char>, std::string, list<char>, etc.

Comment: How did you try to approach it >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something or you have no idea how to do it?

I'll assume you didn't do anything yet.

First of all, you have to find the last consonant. How do you do that. Well, you start from the end and check the letter **until you find a consonant**.
Now, when you find the last consonant, you memorize the position of the consonant and then move **every letter that's to the right of the consonant** to the left.
And lastly, change the last character in the string to the '\0'.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

bool isConsonant(char);

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char s[80];

    // Input the text
    std::cout << "Enter the text: ";
    std::cin.getline(s,80,'\n');

    // Creating string object
    std::string text(s);
    int length = text.length();

    // Searching for the last consonant
    int i = length - 1;
    while ((!isConsonant(text.at(i)) && (i)))
        i--;

    // Moving every letter after the last consonant one place to the left
    for (int j = i; j < length - 1; j++)
        text.at(j) = text.at(j+1);
    text.at(length-1) = '\0';

    // Printing the text to the standard output
    std::cout << text;
    return 0;
}

bool isConsonant(char c) {
    if (isalpha(c)) {   
        char temp = c;
        if (isupper(c))
            temp = tolower(c);
        return !((temp == 'a') || (temp == 'e') || (temp == 'i') || (temp == 'o') || (temp == 'u'));
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: Of course there are other ways to do this, and you should try to think of them. This is a first thing that came to my mind.